# Is it possible to destroy the air-ship?

Tags: rayman-origins

On the final level of Moody Clouds, you find yourself chasing an air-ship on mosquito back. At various points throughout the level, you have an opportunity to shoot at the air-ship, inflicting apparent damage as you shoot off rudders, doors and other various bits of the ship.

At the end of the level, the ship collides with some sort of power core, causing a massive explosion. Is it possible to completely destroy the air-ship before that point, or is the damage incurred by the air-ship merely cosmetic?

Answer (score -1):

I used an autoclicker so it would fire the bullets as fast as possible, and it only destroys the ship until you kill the enemy that is in the bottom, so I guess it's just cosmetic.

Comment: Enemy in the bottom of what? The ship?